# How to connect an Android TV Stick to a pc

Tags: usb, android, hdmi, tv

I have a Coowell Android TV stick:

http://www.gearbest.com/tv-box-mini-pc/pp_484213.html

I'd like to upload an APK file to it.

There are these inputs/outputs on the stick:

- Big USB marked "USB 2.0"
- Small USB marked "DC"
- Small USB marked "OTG"

There is no manual for this one. When I connect the small ones to the Windows nothing happens, except I hear the standard "USB connected" sound. It doesnt show up in the file system or anywhere else.

I was told the big USB is for mouse so that probably wouldn't work either but I don't have that kind of cable to try.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps Plug a 5V DC source into DC - plug a USB stick into the OTG port (you may need a special adaptor) , A keyboard/mouse into "USB 2.0" and attach a HDMI monitor - you my be able drive the system like that .  Otherwise all the above but try the PC into the OTG port and see if the Android OS prompts to share storage when you plug in the PC

Comment: You’re probably better off just using HTTP to transfer the file, using the browser on the Android device. MTP may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your device looks like is following the standard "stick" configuration. If so, the "Big USB 2.0" (USB Type-A receptacle) is a host port, which should support USB 2.0 hubs, so you can connect a keyboard, mouse, and a pen drive to your Android.

The "small USB DC" (micro-B receptacle) is for external power supply only, it should not connect as any USB device.

The other "small USB OTG" is a dual-role (aka OTG) port. With a special adapter (u-B to A receptacle, ID pin grounded in the uB) is can work as USB host port, just as the "big" one. With a regular uB to A cable (ID pin floating), the stick should act as USB device, likely as MTP-class device (Media Transfer Protocol). For Windows PC to connect, the PC should have a USB MTP driver installed, check it [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19153).